# showAsAction=“ifRoom” doesn't behave as it should

Tags: android

I created a basic project with "Minimum required SDK" API 11 to test Action Bar.
Instead of showing action buttons on bar they ended up in action overflow, even the bar was empty. I used the following code.

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

But it started to show action buttons when I added the following namespace.

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and changed the `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`.

As far as I know `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` should work in API 11 and above.

Please help to clear this out.

Comment: If there's not enough room for the item in the action bar, it will appear in the action overflow. try `android:showAsAction= "always"`

Comment: There was plenty of space in the Action Bar as there was no action buttons at all. I tried "always" as well. But nothing happened. As I explained they appeared only after adding  `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` namespace, which supposed to do for API 10 or less.

Comment: Look at the min sdk in your manifest

Answer (score 2):

```
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

xmlns means xml namespace, it makes elements from the xml unique. You should always include this line do desambiguate two elements that share the same name.

More here: http://www.sitepoint.com/xml-namespaces-explained/

You could get rid of version incompability with this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        //set action bar here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you want  to show the action search menu on action  bar

then use

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

   <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: This is some thing else I guess

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I exactly did. Could you please explain the reason behind this?

Comment: for appcompact you need to use it like this.